# Display table rows horizontally in I.E9

Tags: html, css

Below is my code

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 12</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
tr{
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

**Link:** [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c4vev2L/)

I want to display table rows horizontally, if rows width increases the max-width of the div it should come to next row.

The above code is working in I.E 10 + and Chrome and FF.

Here the challenge is not working in I.E 9. 
Any suggestion how to make it work in IE. inline-flex not supported in IE9

I also used **display: table-cell**. But its not increasing the height of the div

Comment: Using wordwrap may work in your case. .wordWrap400{
width:400px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

Comment: Why you are using tables and inline-flex for this purpose? It's an exercise? I think that inline-blocks or float elements it's better and more compatibility.

Comment: IE9 might get confused by the conflicting display properties such as `table-cell` directly inside a `table`. Try to set the display property of all the table elements (table, tbody, tr and td). Or, as Marcos says, don't use a table at all!